# Is there an exhaustive list of functions that can be disabled using disable_functions in PHP?

Tags: php, security

I have always wondered if there is an exhaustive list of functions that could be disabled using [`disable_functions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) in `php.ini`?

I question if there is a specific list that can vs can't be because PHP.net says:

> This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security reasons.

It reads like there are *certain* functions that can be. And *certain* functions that can't be.

Comment: I think this is more of a serverfault, or security question... but, I'll see if I can put in an answer.

Comment: I think it just means that you will list certain functions,  not that there are functions you can't list.